# Add .pcf bitmap lemon font to the urxvt .Xdefault config

Tags: fonts, rxvt

I found this i3 setup (http://dotshare.it/dots/1011/) and want to configure it on my own machine to customize it using this base. Starting with `urxvt`'s config I fail on the `Lemon` fonts at the moment.

As I downloaded `lemon` from the AUR package

I was able to find lemon fonts in format `.pcf` here https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/phallus-fonts-git/ .

Installing it showed me:

```
~ $ ls /usr/share/fonts/misc/
fonts.dir            lemon-ISO8859-15.pcf  lemon-ISO8859-4.pcf  lemon.pcf            uushi-ISO8859-15.pcf  uushi-ISO8859-4.pcf  uushi.pcf
lemon-ISO8859-1.pcf  lemon-ISO8859-2.pcf   lemon-ISO8859-9.pcf  uushi-ISO8859-1.pcf  uushi-ISO8859-2.pcf   uushi-ISO8859-9.pcf
```

So far so good.

```
URxvt.font:xft:lemon:pixelsize=10
URxvt.boldFont:xft:Lemon:bold:pixelsize=10
URxvt.italicfont:xft:Lemon:italic:pixelsize=10
URxvt.bolditalicFont:xft:Lemon:bold:italic:pixelsize=10
URxvt*letterSpace: -1
URxvt*allow_bold: true
! URXVT FONT SETTINGS
!------------------------------------------------
Xft.autohint: true
Xft.antialias: true
Xft.hinting: true
Xft.hintstyle: hintslight
Xft.rgba: rgb
Xft.lcdfilter: lcddefault
```

*pushed from emacs by https://github.com/xetra11/termbin-minor-mode*

Here you can see the font specific configuration I downloaded. It depends on the font-alias `Lemon`.

Running

```
~ $ fc-match Lemon
DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
```

tells me that there isn't one defined therefore it uses the fallback font. I checked `/usr/shares/fonts` for any `fonts.alias` but none was yet available.

So I tried to apply the full name of the font for instance `lemon-ISO8859-1`

```
 URxvt.font:xft:lemon-ISO8859-1:pixelsize=10
```

Which resulted in the fallback font but with bigger font size somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/64nqt0/trying_to_use_bitmap_fonts_in_urxvt_is_just_not/

Actually the *real* name is only findable when using `fc-list`